# A* pathfinding slow

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, maze

I am currently working on a A* search algorithm. The algorithm would just be solving text file mazes. I know that the A* algorithm is supposed to be very quick in finding the finish. Mine seems to take 6 seconds to find the path in a 20x20 maze with no walls. It does find the finish with the correct path it just takes forever to do so.

If I knew which part of code was the problem I would just post that but I really have no idea what is going wrong. So here is the algorithm that I use...

```
 while(!openList.empty()) {  
    visitedList.push_back(openList[index]);
    openList.erase(openList.begin() + index);

    if(currentCell->x_coor == goalCell->x_coor && currentCell->y_coor == goalCell->y_coor)          
    }
        FindBestPath(currentCell);
        break;
    }

    if(map[currentCell->x_coor+1][currentCell->y_coor] != wall)
    {
    openList.push_back(new SearchCell(currentCell->x_coor+1,currentCell->y_coor,currentCell));
    }
    if(map[currentCell->x_coor-1][currentCell->y_coor] != wall) 
    {
        openList.push_back(new SearchCell(currentCell->x_coor-1,currentCell->y_coor,currentCell));
    }
    if(map[currentCell->x_coor][currentCell->y_coor+1] != wall) 
    {
        openList.push_back(new SearchCell(currentCell->x_coor,currentCell->y_coor+1,currentCell));
    }
    if(map[currentCell->x_coor][currentCell->y_coor-1] != wall) 
    {
        openList.push_back(new SearchCell(currentCell->x_coor,currentCell->y_coor-1,currentCell));
    }

    for(int i=0;i<openList.size();i++) {
        openList[i]->G = openList[i]->parent->G + 1;
        openList[i]->H = openList[i]->ManHattenDistance(goalCell);
    }

    float bestF = 999999;
    index = -1;

    for(int i=0;i<openList.size();i++) {
        if(openList[i]->GetF() < bestF) {
            for(int n=0;n<visitedList.size();n++) {
                if(CheckVisited(openList[i])) {
                    bestF = openList[i]->GetF();
                    index = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(index >= 0) {
        currentCell = openList[index];
    }
}
```

I know this code is messy and not the most efficient way to do things but I think it should still be faster then what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I would use something like ctime (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/) and start timing different operations you are doing to find where the majority of your computation time is spent.  It is hard to tell where an algorithm is spending time sometimes and I have found this to be a good way of finding it when all else fails.

Comment: BTW, I don't want to nitpick, but the correct name for the distance is Manhattan (like the city, because it was inspired in the city blocks).

Answer (score 1):

Your 20x20 maze has no walls, and therefore many, many routes which are all the same length. I'd estimate trillions of equivalent routes, in fact. It doesn't seem so bad when you take that into account.

Of course, since your heuristic looks perfect, you should get a big benefit from excluding routes that are heuristically predicted to be *precisely* as long as the best route known so far. (This is safe if your heuristic is correct, i.e. never overestimates the remaining distance).

Comment: A* runs in O(n log n) - for a 20x20 maze (n=400), there is no reason it should take anywhere near 6 seconds.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft In an `n x n` maze with no walls, a good implementation should run in `O(n log(n))` time with the log factor coming from heap manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

`openList.erase` is O(n), and the for-loop beginning with `for(int i=0;i<openList.size();i++)` is O(n^2) due to the call to `CheckVisited` - these are called every iteration, making your overall algorithm O(n^3).  A* *should* be O(n log n).

---

Try changing `openList` to a priority-queue like it's supposed to be, and `visitedList` to a hash table.  The entire `for` loop can then be replaced by a `dequeue` - make sure you check if `visitedList.Contains(node)` *before* enqueuing!

Also, there is no need to recalculate the `ManHattenDistance` for every node every iteration, since it never changes.

Comment: I check for this when I am finding the next cell. It is another function that returns true if the cell is not in the visited list.

Comment: @JakeRunzer that check is not working.  If the check was working properly, then you'd have to generated at most 400 paths.  Even if everything else was low level polynomial, you'd be taking way less than 6 seconds, even in a slow language (which C++ is not).

Comment: I will change the open and visited list as you said. Also how would I prevent from recalculating the manhattan distance every time?

Comment: @Jake: Calculate it when enqueing a node.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a big hint.

If ever you find two paths to the same cell, you can always throw away the longer one.  If there is a tie, you can throw away the second one to get there.

If you implement that, with no other optimizations, the search would become more than acceptably fast.

Secondly the A* algorithm should only bother backtracking if the length to the current cell plus the heuristic **exceeds** the length to the current cell plus the heuristic for any other node.  If you implement that, then it should directly find a path and stop.  To facilitate that you need to store paths in a priority queue (typically implemented with a heap), not a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you constantly backtracking?

The A* algorithm backtracks when the current best solution becomes worse than another previously visited route. In your case, since there are no walls, all routes are good and never die (and as MSalters correctly pointed, there are several of them). When you take a step, your route becomes worse than all the others that are one step shorter.

If that is true, this may account for the time taken by your algorithm.